# How detect in javascript :hover on :before element

Tags: javascript, css

How detect in js :hover in element :

```
.box-cart:after{}
```

I wan't to show another div in other parent child when

```
.box-cart:after:hover{}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: duplicate ? Realy ? Where ?

Comment: That's why it's a **possible** duplicate. The subject if this question and the linked one is JS/JQ control of pseudo elements..and the answer is..you can't....yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pseudo-elements aren't elements, and currently you can't access them via the DOM. So you can't hook event handlers on them. As far as I can tell, you also can't apply pseudo-classes like `:hover` to them in CSS.